# Logic of discrete r.v.s conditional on continuous PDFs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity

Say I have a coin flip, which I'll call X, that outputs tails with probability shown by PDF

$$
f_x = 2b 
$$

where the bias b is drawn from B, which is another r. v. with a uniform distribution over [0,1].

If I compute $P(X|b)$ over the entire set B, I get $P(X) = 1$. Now say I flip the coin again, and call this $X_1$. Then, $P(X_1|X) = 2b * 2b$ because

$$
P(b|X) = P(X|b=B)P(B)/P(X) = 2b * 1 / 1
$$
$$
P(X_1|X) = P(X_1|X,b)P(b|X) = 2b * 2b
$$

This doesn't make sense to me because I've already calculated that $P(X) = 1$ always so there ought to be no probability of getting heads for both $X$ and $X_1$. Is $P(X)$ not supposed to be 1 or am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks.

Comment: What probabilities are you computing? What is $P(X)$? What is $q$?

Comment: Sorry, my example was bad. I've edited the question to make things more clear.

Comment: No, you haven't, really.  It is still rather obscure.

Comment: I've edited it again. Could you tell me which areas I should focus on?

Comment: Here are a couple of areas to improve.  The title indicates a focus on continuous PDFs, but you first introduce a discrete probability distribution (coin flip) with a parameter $b$ supposedly drawn randomly from "a uniform distribution over $[0,1]$."  You should articulate that there is a random process for $X$ which does realize a particular $b$, or else that there is a joint distribution for $X$ and $b$, both random variables that are only realized together with each coin flip.